# Lua check if a file is open or not

Tags: lua

I'm trying to script a lua file to check if a certain file is open. Then I want it to close that file if it is open. I know how to check if the file exist but I need to know how to check if the file is open, meaning the file is running.

Comment: Define "the file is running".

Answer (score 4):

Lua, like C, C++, and pretty much every other language, can only close files that it opens *itself*. You cannot close files open by other people (not with standard Lua calls); this would be **incredibly** rude.

So you can't test to see if a file is opened by someone else. Nor can you close *their* file. There may be system API calls you could make to do this, but you would have to give Lua scripts access to those APIs yourself. Lua's standard libraries can't do this.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to check which if any programs have a given file open.
first thing that comes to mind is parsing the output of lsof on linux.

```
fd = io.popen("lsof path/to/my/file")
fileopened = (#fd:read("a*") > 0)
```

Comment: If your on linux and you're absolutely sure that you won't hurt anyone (or your a BSOF and you don't care), or it's your own process that has a file open, you could kill the application with `fuser`

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a hacky way to do it, but it works:

```
processname = "process_name_here.exe"

filedata = io.popen("tasklist /NH /FO CSV /FI \"IMAGENAME eq "..processname.."\"")
output = filedata:read()
filedata:close()

if output ~= "INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria." then
    -- Program is running. Close the program
    os.execute("taskkill -im "..processname)
else
    -- Program is not running
end
```

Just make sure to replace "process_name_here.exe" with the process name that shows up in task manager

Alternatively you can just use this to close it without checking if it was actually running:

```
os.execute("taskkill -im process_name_here.exe")
```