# Lua check if a file is open

Tags: lua

I use:

```
file = io.open(path)
```

to open a file specified by the path. Now, after some actions, I would use `file:close()` to close the file but there are some times that I didn't even open a file to close it after. How can I check whether a file has been open or not?

Comment: This condition is always false =/

Comment: check out `io.type` function. but this check only descriptor, not file it self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hjpotter92 suggestion works, the condition is not always false:

```
> if file then print("File was opened") else print("What File?") end
What File?
> file = io.open("file.txt")
> if file then print("File was opened") else print("What File?") end
File was opened
> file:close()
> file = nil -- assign to nil after closing the file.
> if file then print("File was opened") else print("What File?") end
What File?
>
```

if you follow this pattern then closing only an open file is easy:

```
   if math.random() < .5 then
      file = open("file.txt") -- maybe it opened
   end

   if file then -- close only if opened
     file:close()
     file = nil
   end
```

A file is open if and only if it exists (not nil).

Comment: Didn't assign nil to file and that's because it was always showing false to me. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard using standard Lua calls to check if a file is open, however if it is just one script accessing the file You could set a variable to True when you open the file and check for it before closing it.

You may find this page helpful:
[Lua check if a file is open or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589706/lua-check-if-a-file-is-open-or-not)